# How to insert array value into table using logic app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

[image]when a http request is received. i need to insert the array value into a table. in my case the array is response required.

I used these things: when a http request is received and i used **parse JSON** and i used for each loop then inside the for-each i used **insert entity** but it's throwing an error. if anybody knows how to implement let me know the answer.

i used expression for RRT as : body('Parse_JSON')['ResponseRequired'][0]['ResponseRequiredType']

json schema

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"properties": {
    "AssetErrorCode": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "AssetErrorDesc": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "AssetId": {
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "CustomerId": {
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "ResponseRequired": {
        "items": [
            {
                "properties": {
                    "ResponseRequiredAdditionalData": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ResponseRequiredAddress": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ResponseRequiredFrequency": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ResponseRequiredType": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "ResponseRequiredType",
                    "ResponseRequiredFrequency",
                    "ResponseRequiredAddress",
                    "ResponseRequiredAdditionalData"
                ],
                "type": "object"
            },
            {
                "properties": {
                    "ResponseRequiredAdditionalData": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ResponseRequiredAddress": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ResponseRequiredFrequency": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ResponseRequiredType": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "ResponseRequiredType",
                    "ResponseRequiredFrequency",
                    "ResponseRequiredAddress",
                    "ResponseRequiredAdditionalData"
                ],
                "type": "object"
            },
            {
                "properties": {
                    "ResponseRequiredAdditionalData": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ResponseRequiredAddress": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ResponseRequiredFrequency": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ResponseRequiredType": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "ResponseRequiredType",
                    "ResponseRequiredFrequency",
                    "ResponseRequiredAddress",
                    "ResponseRequiredAdditionalData"
                ],
                "type": "object"
            }
        ],
        "type": "array"
    },
    "ServiceKey": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"required": [
    "CustomerId",
    "ServiceKey",
    "AssetId",
    "AssetErrorCode",
    "AssetErrorDesc",
    "ResponseRequired"
],
"type": "object"
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used this expression : items('For_each')?['ResponseRequiredAddress']

solved the issue

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.